# Review queue on mobile site - why do we still not have this feature?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, review

**Currently, the mobile version of the site has no link to the review system,** is it possible to have that available? I often use Biology SE on my phone and perform a fair amount of review tasks, but to get to the review system I have to use the desktop version of the site. It would make it easier for users to keep on top of the review tasks if this facility was more accessible.

[image]

**Could stack exchange add the review queue to the top bar in the mobile site?**

E.g.

[image]