# Is the mobile review queue really a long term goal?

Tags: discussion, review, mobile-web

Three and a half years ago one user [asked the following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148616/review-option-on-mobile-phone-not-available):

> The other day I was looking at the stackoverflow site on my Android
>   mobile phone. All is made very nice and all, but I could not find the
>   Review button/link. Is it being implemented, did I miss it, or it is
>   not available?

To which a developer responded:

> We currently do not have a mobile version of review. You can visit
>   review on a mobile device however it will not be optimized for a
>   mobile device. We have a longer term goal of making a mobile version.

In the meantime many have come back and asked for the review queue to be added, resulting in those questions being (correctly) closed as duplicates. My only question here [was exactly that, which I asked on biology meta and got migrated here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273346/review-queue-on-mobile-site-why-do-we-still-not-have-this-feature). However, given that over three years have passed since producing the mobile version of the review queue was described as a *"longer term goal"* of stack exchange, I think it is reasonable to ask the question; *when* is the mobile review queue coming (can they give a target date)? Are SE still even planning on making it available?

---

*Note, I don't think this can be considered a duplicate of the linked question. Here I am asking whether SE still plan on introducing the feature and for specific detail of when. The linked question and answer are old posts (so the situation could reasonably be different now - e.g. SE may have abandoned the plans) and the answer only gives a vague timeline.*

Comment: As a feature request, this is still a duplicate. Retagged as a discussion, since you don't ask to actually do something (it's already asked), but rather what is the status on this.

Answer (score 3):

Five years later and the review queues can be used on a mobile screen (mostly). You will need to use the "full site" link at the bottom of the page if you're looking at the old mobile view, then the review queues will show up in the top bar for those who have access. (And eventually the old mobile views will go away too.)

There are still some issues (notably, it is tricky to edit), but otherwise it's exactly what you need. See the [review queue redesign announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/323179) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The last note on this is from [January 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273346/245360). Animuson closed another question on the mobile review queue as a duplicate of the same question you mention. And there have been [many other questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review+mobile-web?sort=newest) about this in the last years, all with minimal information on the timeline.

From my experience, there is not much emphasis on the mobile experience on anything other than reading, asking and answering. Bugs in the UI take months to be fixed. The same is true for the iOS and Android apps. So I think this is still on the long-term '6-8 weeks' planning.

I doubt if the form factor is actually suitable for reviewing, but that is just my personal opinion (I sometimes do review from a mobile device, but that isn't ideal now).